# Discord.py, if statement not passing despite being true

Tags: python, discord.py

When I attempt to compare the current users game to a predetermined string, it fails to pass even if they are the same thing.

```
@client.event
async def on_presence_update(prev,cur):
  print(cur.activity)
  if cur.activity=='RimWorld':
    print('Playing RW')
    await message.send(f'{cur.mention} is playing RimWorld, a colony simulation game.')
```

Output:
RimWorld

Comment: have you checked datatype

Comment: Try `cur.activity.name`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Just because the representation when printing looks like that doesn't mean it's actually a string

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a `discord.Activity` instance, that isn‘t a string. To compare it, you have to use the `name` attribute of the Activity instance

Comment: It does implement a function that returns the value of the name if being printed